# How do I check two different conditions in MASM?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, masm

I need to check if a user input (negative integer) is within two ranges either between [-200, -100] or [-50, -1].

```
UPPER = -100
LOWER = -200
UPPER2 = -1
LOWER2 = -50    

getData:
     mov       eax, numCount
     add       eax, 1
     mov       numCount, eax
     mov       edx, OFFSET thirdNumPrompt
     call WriteString
     call ReadInt
     mov       userNum, eax

     cmp       eax, LOWER
     jl         numAddition
     cmp       eax, UPPER2
     jg         numAddition
     add       eax, total
     mov       total,eax
     loop       getData
```

I have this right now and it just checks if the integer is between -200 and -1 but I want to exclude the integers between -51 and -99. How would I do that? numAddition is the next step of the program that I want it to run once the user inputs a number that is out of range.

Comment: A range check is really just two individual tests.  So, we simply do both checks, one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

> I have this right now and it just checks if the integer is between -200 and -1 but I want to exclude the integers between -51 and -99. How would I do that?

### Solution 1

The loop ends on the first number that is out of range:

```
getData:
    ...

    cmp  eax, LOWER
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER
    jle  .WithinRange
    cmp  eax, LOWER2
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER2
    jg   .OutOfRange
.WithinRange:
    add  eax, total
    mov  total, eax
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
.Done:

    ...

.OutOfRange:
    ...                  ; numAddition
```

### Solution 2

The loop runs till the end but the numbers that are out of range get treated differently:

```
getData:
    ...

    cmp  eax, LOWER
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER
    jle  .WithinRange
    cmp  eax, LOWER2
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER2
    jle  .WithinRange
.OutOfRange:
    ...                  ; numAddition
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
    jmp  .Done
.WithinRange:
    add  eax, total
    mov  total, eax
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
.Done:
```

> a user input (**negative** integer)

If you can be absolutely sure that the number is negative, then next versions do it with 3 instead of 4 `cmp`'s. The reason this works is that UPPER2 = **-1** precisely.

### Solution 3

The loop ends on the first number that is out of range:

```
getData:
    ...

    cmp  eax, LOWER
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER
    jle  .WithinRange
    cmp  eax, LOWER2
    jl   .OutOfRange
.WithinRange:
    add  eax, total
    mov  total, eax
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
.Done:

    ...

.OutOfRange:
    ...                  ; numAddition
```

### Solution 4

The loop runs till the end but the numbers that are out of range get treated differently:

```
getData:
    ...

    cmp  eax, LOWER
    jl   .OutOfRange
    cmp  eax, UPPER
    jle  .WithinRange
    cmp  eax, LOWER2
    jge  .WithinRange
.OutOfRange:
    ...                  ; numAddition
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
    jmp  .Done
.WithinRange:
    add  eax, total
    mov  total, eax
    dec  ecx
    jnz  getData
.Done:
```